# nslookup working fine but ruby http call throwing error - getaddrinfo: Try again (SocketError)

Tags: ruby, ubuntu

nslookup and dig are resolving the address but ruby program throwing error.

here is the stack trace

```
10: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rest-client-2.0.2/lib/restclient.rb:67:in `get'
 9: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rest-client-2.0.2/lib/restclient/request.rb:52:in `execute'
 8: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rest-client-2.0.2/lib/restclient/request.rb:145:in `execute'
 7: from /usr/local/bundle/gems/rest-client-2.0.2/lib/restclient/request.rb:715:in `transmit'
 6: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http.rb:909:in `start'
 5: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http.rb:920:in `do_start'
 4: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http.rb:935:in `connect'
 3: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/timeout.rb:103:in `timeout'
 2: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/timeout.rb:93:in `block in timeout'
 1: from /usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http.rb:936:in `block in connect'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.5.0/net/http.rb:939:in `rescue in block in connect': Failed to open TCP connection to ******:80 (getaddrinfo: Try again) (SocketError)
```

Comment: It's not answering on port 80 as the error says. Try connecting on the correct port (i.e. 443 if SSL is used).

Comment: I can reach the host using http, hence port 80. Actually I am able to reach the server in browser.